# Bluetooth audio on windows 7 is horrible but on windows 10 it works properly

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth

I have a Toshiba Protege R700 which has windows 10 installed. I decided to install windows 7 and daily drive it for fun. Everything sailed smoothly except of the bluetooth audio. I tried every driver version in existance but the same thing kept happening: The sound was very choppy at times, the delay was very high and the range horrible. Sometimes the sound would cut off from one ear entirely for a few seconds. Why is this happening? This laptop originally came with windows 7 so everything should be compatible

Comment: "every driver version in existence" - there wouldn't too many of them for Windows 7.

Comment: Some times, hardware, simply isn’t compatible with Windows 7. Is there a reason you are purposely using Windows 7 which is not supported and has numerous security issues.

Comment: To paraphrase Sam Johnson, "Windows 7 operation is like a dog's walking on his hind legs. It is not done well; but you are surprised to find it done at all.”

Answer (score 1):

> I decided to install windows 7 and daily drive it for fun.

Windows 7 is so old and so long out of support that it does not update any more.

So you are likely missing Bluetooth Audio drivers and/or driver updates. Also missing APIs, DLLs, and other substructure requirements.

There is nothing you can do anymore to fix Windows 7.

Since what you want cannot be done, don't use Windows 7 but use your Windows 10 system which works.